# Как запросить пароль Windows в Python?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

Я хочу запросить пароль Windows (Вот так выглядит диалог):
https://miro.medium.com/max/914/1*qClfSjET8kTA9isUDTEw8g.png
Но я не понимаю, как это сделать. Я уже пробовал это делать:

```py
ctypes.windll.credui.CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT, "E", None, 0, "LOL", CRED_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH, "PASSWORD", CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH, CREDUIWIN_CHECKBOX, CREDUIWIN_GENERIC)
```

Но и это не работает, просто возвращает 31 и ничего не делает.

Как мне запросить аутентификацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй через pywin32. демка должна работать: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Demos/win32cred_demo.py

Comment: Работает, но какое-то старое окошко. Можно как-то получить такое? https://miro.medium.com/max/914/1*qClfSjET8kTA9isUDTEw8g.png

Comment: (Ссылка не полностью кликается, скопируй и вставь)